Applied for Germany visa in the UK, but traveling from India. Will there be a problem?
I'm a PhD student in the UK going to Germany in July for a summer school. I have an appointment at the German embassy here in the UK for the visa application. However, I will be in India for the beginning of my summer vacation, and would like to travel directly from India to Germany for the summer school. Is this going to be a problem considering that I applied for a visa at the German embassy in the UK? Someone advised me to travel from India to UK first and then travel from UK to Germany, but I don't see why I should do that.

Does this answer your question? Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?

@DavidRecallsMonica Not at all. That's a completely different question.

Seems to me to cover the same subject. You have (or will have) a visa for Germany, and you're asking if you have to stop by the UK first on your way to Germany. You don't have to do that, you can enter Germany directly.

@DavidRecallsMonica I don't think it does. Besides stating the obvious (that UK isn't a Schengen region) my main question is whether I need to be traveling from where I applied (the UK) rather than which Schengen region I can enter first (for instance, if I could visit Spain before going to Germany). For me Germany is the main destination, therefore having to stop in the UK first is in no way related to the other question. In fact the answer to that suggests I have some freedom to enter a different region, which is the opposite of my question.

FWIW, I think your analysis is correct. You have (or will have) a visa for Germany. With that visa, you can enter Germany. It is irrelevant hat the visa was issued by a  German government authority located outside of Germany.

@DavidRecallsMonica Thanks for this.

Since you're going to the embassy, why not just speak to them then?

Just take proof that you will return the UK when traveling from India to Germany.

@JackAidley One of the requirements for the visa application is my travel itinerary i.e. purchased plane tickets. I needed the answer to my question in order to buy them right?

There is no reason this should be a problem. There is no restriction and no requirement regarding where you are entering the Schengen area from.

Thinking on the other side, if some methods of entry had more relaxed scrutiny, the criminals would prefer these. You only need one weak link to break a chain with thousands.
